# emulateTransitionEnd in bootstrap.js , where is it coming from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was just debugging modal.js and came across the following piece of code :

```
 that.$element.find('.modal-dialog') // wait for modal to slide in
      .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
        that.$element.trigger('focus').trigger(e)
      })
      .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
    that.$element.trigger('focus').trigger(e)
```

my question is about the following line :

```
emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
```

What is that? A jQuery function? A custom function in bootstrap?

I googled about this function, but could barely find anything, I am guessing it's a custom bootstrap function. But then I don't see this function in my modal.js (a subset of bootstrap.js) at all .

I saw the following somewhere : [link](https://www.omniref.com/js/npm/akashacms-theme-bootstrap/0.1.8/symbols/$.fn.emulateTransitionEnd#line=52).

What is this `emulateTransitionEnd` really ? And where is it defined and what is it doing ?

You can find the line I am talking about here : [line 99 modal.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L99)

Comment: Lost your copy of grep? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/ad379ffb4a0fde7416ae076e68141300fc583018/js/transition.js#L36

Comment: @cvrebert , ok so i have just Jquery and modal.js and i'am making a modal , i don't have transition.js , and my cosnole does't show any errors ! WHYYY ???

Comment: If you don't load the transitions module, then [`$.support.transition`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/bcf7dd38b5ab180256e2e4fb5da0369551b3f082/js/transition.js#L46) will be undefined, so [transitions will merely be disabled](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/442d2dd458c6283c7ecb75c6eb7cb4bcee916eab/js/modal.js#L125)

Comment: so given the following statement `$.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
        this.$backdrop
          .one('bsTransitionEnd', callbackRemove)
          .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION) :
        callbackRemove() `.   callbackRemove() will fire , if i don't include transitions.js ??

Answer (score 12):

It's a custom Bootstrap function declared here

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/83bfff7f0765503b990b96c303eef67009e48d77/js/transition.js#L36

It's a functions that fires event (once) on $.support.transition.end

**$.support.transition.end** contains one of these events:

- webkitTransitionEnd
- transitionend
- oTransitionEnd
- otransitionend
- transitionend

You can find more informations here

[how to listen to the end of a bootstrap animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914760/how-to-listen-to-the-end-of-a-bootstrap-animation)